# Reaching AngularJS functions across files using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

So I am learning Jasmine and I am trying to apply it to a very large project right now to test some Angular JS methods. I have a Jasmine test file, which shows me the results from the tests, however it will only run/reach methods within that same JS test file. What I am trying to do is access methods in other files (different locations of my C# solution) and I am not sure how to do this.

Right now I am just using the following as a sample function (helloWorld) and test (describe).

```
//method to test
function helloWorld() {
    return "Hello world!";
}

//actual test
describe("Hello world", function () {
    it("says hello", function () {
        expect("/app/views/dashboard/clientQuoteView.html/"+helloWorld()).toEqual("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

I am trying to stick `helloWorld()` in a different file, and get the result passed back to my `describe()` statement. How do I do this or point to my method correctly?

Lets say my pathway for the jasmine test file (the describe method) is `ProjectName/app/tests/jasminetests.js`, and I stick the `helloWorld()` function at pathway `ProjectName/app/services/calculate.js`

Here is an example of what the jasmine page looks like, it currently is showing 5 of 6 (the 5 are within that js test file, while the 6th is the test trying to find and run the helloWorld method in a different file). *It is not error'ing for the 6th test because it cannot find that helloWorld method.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the helloworld method in an Angular service and inject it into the test. This way it will be available from any test or file.

Here is a quick example of how to inject it once you have created the service:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/how-to-inject-angular-dependencies-in-jasmine-unit-tests

The idea is that you register the service with angular and just rely on angular dependency injection.

Comment: This link is dead. Please replace the link with one that works.

Comment: @SethDifley Sorry about that. Updated